# Dynamic view in Asp Mvc for authenticated users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Iam creating an Asp mvc 5 website. Iam adding users for my website so i used identity 2 authentication mechanisms. its working correctly. But even after login the login and register buttons are there. After login i want to show an actionlink named "Managa My Account".

How to automatically hide login and register button upon login and show logoff button?
how to add custom menus if an user logs in? I have searched for a lot. but only webforms examples are showing up. Can anyone help me with it? Can you give some idea  on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show the view you are talking about?  Typically I use something like `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` inside an if for this but it's hard to say exactly what to put without your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in the view where you want to show after authentication,

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated()){
    // Your expected action link
    @Html.ActionLink("Manage my account", "Action", "Controller")
    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Action", "Controller")
}
```

For not authenticated users,

```
@if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated()){
    // Your expected action link
    @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Action", "Controller")
    @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Action", "Controller")
}
```